# Stick div to bottom of parent chat window

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the chat input (chatArea) to float at the bottom of the blue div container and make it stick there while scrolling through the chat.

any help is appreciated, thank you.

Here's a fiddle of what I have now:
https://jsfiddle.net/oyja38t5/

html:

```
<div class="chatContainer">
    <div id="messages">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
       <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chatArea">
        <form action="" id="cSubmitButton">
            <input id="chatInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type your guess here!"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.chatContainer {
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #90C3D4;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 8px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.chatContainer p {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0;
} 

.chatArea {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#chatInput {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}

#cSubmitButton {
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) `position: sticky` should be `position: fixed`. But you can also do it without a fixed div. Since you already added a scrollbar to your chat container why don't you just place the chatArea under the messages and add a surrounding div: https://jsfiddle.net/keoxb8z5/

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking for

```css
.chatContainer {
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #90C3D4;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 8px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.chatContainer p {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0;
} 

.chatArea {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 100%;
}

#chatInput {

    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    
}

#cSubmitButton {
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatContainer">
    <div id="messages">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
       <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chatArea">
        <form action="" id="cSubmitButton">
            <input id="chatInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type your guess here!"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```